# What does it mean to use optional binding on a single element with and without optional chaining?

Tags: swift

What does it mean to call optional chaining on a single element with optional binding?

For example, are the following two result in the same behind the scene?

Optional Binding

```
var str:String!

if let s = str {

}
```

Optional Binding with single element optional chaining

```
var str:String!

if let s = str? {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those two examples are functionally the same, but why would you try to use optional chaining in that scenario? Optional chaining is for when you want to get the propery or method of a variable but you don't know if it's nil or not. If you only need to check the variable itself, just use optional binding like in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

See the section of the Swift book on "Optional-Chaining Expression" (in Language Reference -> Expressions -> Postfix expressions).

> On its own, the postfix ? operator simply returns the value of its
>   argument as an optional.

You are using optional chaining "on its own", i.e. not inside a postfix expression. Therefore, the `?` operator evaluates to an optional, but it already takes an optional. So the two pieces of code are identical.